# jQuery show date based on month

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have Month and Year picker for that I used this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('.date-picker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        minDate: 0,
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
          $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    .ui-datepicker-calendar {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="startDate">Date :</label>
  <input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
</body>

</html>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.date-picker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    minDate: 0,
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">


<label for="startDate">Date :</label>
<input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
```

It's working fine. My requirement is if I select Aug 2017 I need to show all date in different different div. SO based on Month & Year selection date should show

For ex:

Aug 2017

```
div 1    div 1     div 3     div 3 
1          2         3         4
Sunday    Monday   Tuesday    wednesday
```

like this i want to show all date for particular month

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're actually asking, here.  For instance, you indicate that August 1, 2017 should go in a div with the word 'Sunday', but August 1, 2017 was a Tuesday.  Can you make it more clear what your expected behavior is, after selecting a month and year?  Is this a homework assignment to dynamically build a calendar, for instance?

Comment: I select Aug 2017 then i want to show all date in aug moth in separate separate div

Comment: Same way if i select next moth also

Comment: So, to clarify, you want to dynamically create 'X' divs, where 'X' is the number of days in the selected month.  You then want to label each (numbered) div with the correct day of the week for the given date?  This really does smell like a homework project to me.

Comment: Yes Exactly thats what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this simple code will help you. Use this and enjoy. 
Thanks..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <style type="text/css">
.datediv{

    border:1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var weekday = new Array(7);
        weekday[0] = "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        weekday[5] = "Friday";
        weekday[6] = "Saturday";
$(function() {


    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        minDate: 0,
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            $d = new Date(inst.selectedYear, parseInt(inst.selectedMonth)+1, 0).getDate();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
            html='';
            for(i=1;i<=$d;i++){
                console.log(inst.selectedYear+'-'+(parseInt(inst.selectedMonth)+1)+'-'+i);
                d = new Date(inst.selectedYear+'-'+(parseInt(inst.selectedMonth)+1)+'-'+i);
                console.log(d);
                n = weekday[d.getDay()];
                html += '<div class="datediv'+i+'">div-'+i+'<br><span id="div-'+i+'">'+n+'</span></div><br>';
            }
            $('#datecontent').html(html);
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="startDate">Date :</label>
    <input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
    <div id="datecontent">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How to pass dynamic Id here

Comment: what do you mean by pass dynamic id?

Comment: okay I got it. I was updated code now you can see particular div with id and particular day also with id. may be miscommunication. Tell me I was right or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're making a calendar. This code should work:

```js
var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat: 'MM yy',
  minDate: 0,
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
    $d = new Date(inst.selectedYear, parseInt(inst.selectedMonth) + 1, 0).getDate();
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
    html = '';
    for (i = 1; i <= $d; i++) {
      d = new Date(inst.selectedYear + '-' + (parseInt(inst.selectedMonth) + 1) + '-' + i);
      n = weekday[d.getDay()];
      html += '<div class="datediv">' + i + '<br>' + n + '</div><br>';
    }
    $('#datecontent').html(html);
  }
});
```

```css
.datediv {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<label for="startDate">Date :</label>
<input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
<div id="datecontent">
</div>
```