# angularjs status display on jquery div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using Month Year Picker in jQuery and it's working fine.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```js
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

$(function() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
       /* minDate: 0,*/
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            $d = new Date(inst.selectedYear, parseInt(inst.selectedMonth)+1, 0).getDate();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
            html='';
            for(i=1;i<=$d;i++){
                //console.log(inst.selectedYear+'-'+(parseInt(inst.selectedMonth)+1)+'-'+i);
                d = new Date(inst.selectedYear+'-'+(parseInt(inst.selectedMonth)+1)+'-'+i);
                //console.log(d);
                n = weekday[d.getDay()];
                html +='<div class="dateMain">';
                html += '<div class="dates datediv'+i+'">'+i+'</div>';
                html += '<div class="test">status</div>';
                html += '</div>';
            }
            $('#datecontent').html(html);
            $scope.allReport();
        }
    });
});
```

**allreport** function will return response

```js
$scope.allReport = function() {
       $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'api/admin/report'
        }).success( function (data) {
                $scope.data = data.data;
                console.log($scope.data);
          }).error(function (response){
                console.log("error");  
       });
}
```

my **response**

```js
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        my1:{
                {
                    "id": 66,
                    "cuid": 20,
                    "name": "my1",
                    "created_at": "2018-03-09 00:00:00",
                    "updated_at": "2018-03-09 00:00:00",
                    "time": "07:19 PM",
                    "status": "D"
                }
                {
                    "id": 65,
                    "cuid": 20,
                    "name": "my1",
                    "created_at": "2018-03-07 00:00:00",
                    "updated_at": "2018-03-07 00:00:00",
                    "time": "07:39 PM",
                    "status": "D"
                }
        },
         my2:{
                {
                    "id": 63,
                    "cuid": 21,
                    "name": "my2",
                    "created_at": "2018-03-07 00:00:00",
                    "updated_at": "2018-03-07 00:00:00",
                    "time": "07:39 PM",
                    "status": "D"
                }
                {
                    "id": 64,
                    "cuid": 21,
                    "name": "my2",
                    "created_at": "2018-03-02 00:00:00",
                    "updated_at": "2018-03-05 00:00:00",
                    "time": "07:01 PM",
                    "status": "D"
                }
        }
    ],
    "message": "User Reportsssss successfully."
}
```

So now I want to display Status on particular date in calendar view for test div

```js
html +='<div class="dateMain">';
html += '<div class="dates datediv'+i+'">'+i+'</div>';
html += '<div class="test">status</div>';
html += '</div>';
```

How can I display the AngularJS status response on correct date div?

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and AngularJS?

Comment: I am not able to find any solution for this month and year picker

Comment: What about this one https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker? Second entry on google while search for "angularjs datepicker".

Comment: I need like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966775/jquery-show-date-based-on-month

Comment: Use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#%2Fdatepicker and you will be fine.